# Create a vector with a runtime defined data type

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, vector, casting, strong-typing

Typically you create a Vector (strongly typed array) specifying a data type like:

```
new Vector<PictureBox>();
```

However I need to create a utility method that should be able to create a vector of any given datatype. Is it possible to specify a type using a variable instead of hard-coding it?

```
var type:Class = PictureBox;
new Vector<type>();
```

Comment: I added a small update to my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot do it exactly the way you want, but you could use a set of classes which implement the same interface, and then type your vector with that interface, e.g.:

```
var list:Vector.<IBox>

class PictureBox implements IBox
class TextBox implements IBox
```

Comment: What?? can you give me an example code snippet of what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Tell me where to begin, I'm assuming you know how to use Interfaces.

Comment: Okay, so you mean declare the vector like `Vector.<IBox` where `PictureBox implements IBox` ??

Comment: I've simplified the text, hopefully it should be helpful for future readers.

Answer (score 2):

I am sure Vector<> has to be strongly typed.